# ZPL - Line Item Detail for Order

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii

We are working to create a ZPL label that will show the line item detail for an order.  Do we have to assign each line item is own FO and FN?  Is it possible to simplify and increment the FO and print the next line item.  Resulting in something like this.

```
QTY DESCRIPTION PRICE
1   ITEM 1      $5.00
1   ITEM 2      $6.00
```

Right now we have something like this, but it just doesn't seem efficient or correct.

```
^XA
^FX ORDER DETAIL
^FX RXi 300dpi
^PR3
^DFLABEL^FS
^FX LABEL HEADER
^FO100,30^A0,30,40^FN1^FS 
^FO500,30^A0,30,40^FN2^FS =
^FO20,350^A0,20,20^FN3^FS 

^FX COLUMN HEADERS
^FO20,65^A0,25,25^^FDQTY^FS
^FO100,65^A0,25,25^FDDESCRIPTION^FS
^FO500,65^A0,25,25^FDPRICE^FS

^FX FIRST ROW
^FO30,100^A0,14,14^FN4^FS
^FO100,100^A0,14,14^FN5^FS
^FO500,100^A0,14,14^FN6^FS

^FX SECOND ROW
^FO30,120^A0,14,14^FN7^FS
^FO100,120^A0,14,14^FN8^FS
^FO500,120^A0,14,14^FN9^FS

^FX THIRD ROW
^FO30,140^A0,14,14^FN10^FS
^FO100,140^A0,14,14^FN11^FS
^FO500,140^A0,14,14^FN12^FS
```

ETC....

```
FN1 = QUANTITY
FN2 = DESCRIPTION
FN3 = PRICE
```

And these come from the database.

Comment: Are you using XML templates, or just directly creating the ZPL in the source system?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to increment the position in ZPL.  If you are creating the ZPL with a another program that you are writing, then use that program to build the ZPL string dynamically.